# Question regarding country

Tags: locale

```
locale = "hy_AM_REVISED"
```

Which country does this locale belong to?

Comment: maybe you should start giving ppl credit - 0% acceptance and with 39 questions is not too cool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Its **Armenian**

Check the [list of all locales](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/Locale-Country-Multilingual/Locale/Country/Multilingual.html).